# How does a server become part of a distributed system?

Tags: gemfire

The GemFire tutorial shows that a locator is started with
gfsh>start locator --name=locator1 --port=55221

In some parts of the tutorial the command to start a server is shown as
gfsh>start server --name=server1 --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager=true --J=-Dgemfire.jmx-manager-start=true --J=-Dgemfire.http-port=8080

In this case, how does the server know the locator on which it will get registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server **always** joins a distributed system (DS) by connecting to a locator. [*]

If you start a locator from within gfsh and then, *in the same session*, start a server, gfsh will know to use the existing locator connection for the new server you are starting. In this case you don't need to explicitly provide a `--locator` option. This is also true when running gfsh with multiple start commands from a script. For example: `gfsh -e "start locator --name=locator1 --port=19991" -e "start server --name=server1" -e "list members"`

[*] Not true for versions of GemFire/Geode < 9.x as older versions can also join a DS using a multicast address/port combo. See the `--mcast-port` option in the docs. However that functionality is deprecated and will not be available in GemFire/Geode >= 9.x so it